# hood.ie with couchDB method to refresh pages with DB change

Tags: couchdb, hoodie

I've started using hood.ie to make a web app.

I wanted to ask is there a convenient way to refresh pages whenever data in the couch db changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function that renders your page, like `render`, you can do this

```
hoodie.store.on("change", render)
```

The `"change"` event will trigger every time something changes in your data, be it because you called on of the `hoodie.store` APIs, or because of a changed synced from remote

Comment: So could I just have that anywhere in my JavaScript say
hoodie.store.on("change", refresh) 
Then have a function called refresh, which reloads the page?

Comment: Yes - i just tried it and it works. hood.ie is pretty amazing!

Comment: This seems to works on occasions but not at others. Any ideas why?

Comment: Might be due to connection issues. Add `hoodie.on("disconnected", handleConnectionError)` to debug that